# Spring Boot multiple databases, different way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First of all sorry for my English.

I need to save information in to different databases, both of them in Oracle SQL developer.

The solutions that I found on internet, all of them are coding in spring, but my project just have a configuration file, where is defined the database, and then how spring knows which database is active, and then is keeping the information there, like magic, I was looking around the internet, and the solution is not working for me...

Maybe you have any idea to how develop this without something like the next:

```
// Datasource method goes here
@Primary
@Bean(name = "datasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.second.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
// LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory goes here
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernet.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).properties(properties).packages("com.example").persistenceUnit("MyEntity").build();
}
```

I think I have defined the datasource in a properties, but then is doing something different to the datasource method.

Comment: If you're trying a different approach ('datasource in properties... something different to the datasource method'), can you show what it is you have so far and what's working vs what's not working? Or are you looking to replace what you currently have with something different?

Comment: hello Emmanuel, welcome to the most important part of your programming experience  ;-)
please take a look at this website that is very useful for issues related to java or spring boot, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases , keep me update about your issue, i can help you!!!

Comment: Changing a little bit the question... 

I have in my application.properties the next:

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_directory?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx

And in my project I have classic, services, repositories, entities etc...

But, this works fine with one datasource, what I mean? I didn't have to do reference to this dataSource for example, when i want to use the method of JPARepository findById(), but if i add a new dataSource, how can i switch when i need the different datasources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, that was a different answer of what I'm expected.

I create two Maven Projects, and then in my ConfigRepo by the spring-application-name I tell wich one were consuming what database. And that's all, problem Solved.